# select distinct query in java map reduce

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce

```
10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
10001|75286|1993-06-24|1994-06-24
```

my target is to remove the dup values and the output be like

```
10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
10001|75286|1993-06-24|1994-06-24
```

I wrote a code as below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class charterSelDistRec {

        public static class Map extends Mapper <LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
            private String tableKey,tableValue;

            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
 throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                    String line = value.toString();
                    String splitarray[] = line.split("\\|",2);
                    tableKey = splitarray[0].trim();
                    tableValue = splitarray[1].trim();

                    context.write(new Text(tableKey), new Text(tableValue));     
                }
        }               

        public static class Reduce extends Reducer <Text, Text, Text, Text> {                         
            public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, Context context) 
                      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                    String ColumnDelim="";
                    String tableOutValue=ColumnDelim+values;
                    context.write(new Text(key), new Text(tableOutValue));

                }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                Configuration conf = new Configuration();
                Job job = new Job(conf,"charterSelDistRec");
                job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename", "root.Dev");
                job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator","|");
                job.setJobName("work_charter_stb.ext_chtr_vod_fyi_mapped");
                job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

                job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

                job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

                job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
                job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


                FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
                FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
                job.setJarByClass(charterSelDistRec.class); 
                job.waitForCompletion(true);
          }
      }
```

but still the output file has dups. Please do let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: In current code, split function is making key as `column 1` and as per your need it should be `column 3`.

Comment: Why it should be column 3. I am trying to remove duplicates value so if key is 10001 still value are repeating

Answer (score 4):

It need not be so complicated. All you have to do is:

1. in mapper, emit each line as key and any value
2. in reducer, just emit the keys and ignore values.

**Sharing code:**

Here is the input:

```
10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
10001|75286|1993-06-24|1994-06-24
```

Here is the code:

```
public class StackRemoveDup {

    public  static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text, Text, NullWritable> {

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable ignore, Text value, Context context)
            throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(value,NullWritable.get());
        }  
    }

    public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, NullWritable, Text, NullWritable> {

      @Override
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<NullWritable> values, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        context.write(key, NullWritable.get());
      }
    }       

  public static void main(String[] args) 
                  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

    Job job = new Job();
    job.setJarByClass(StackRemoveDup.class);
    job.setJobName("StackRemoveDup");

    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
10001|75286|1993-06-24|1994-06-24
10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
```

Comment: we need select distinct a,b,c from table like map and reducer. So I need to emit the values also . Map emits key value pairs so technically the dup values should be removed but its printing them as it is not sure why it does dot pick them as dup

Comment: Shared code. Each row is key here for reducer. Which reducer simply emits as keys and no values.  I am taking advantage of the fact that MR framework sends unique keys to reducer, so you implicitly get output with removed duplicated rows.  Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I wrote a similar code as written by you as attached above any idea why it did not worked. The difference I see in mapper I have written  TableKey=value.toString(0);  How come this will cause a difference

Comment: Its very different code. Or I would say logic. I am using only 2 lines of code rest is all MR framework needs you to write.

in your code you are sending first column as key which is not unique as Arpit rightly pointed out, so you will get all the rows in your reducer for the given key.

You got to send unique keys (as entire row)  to reducer and let the MR framework remove the duplicated rows for you. You don't have to do any splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You have two records in first row, and one record in sec row. And once reading in done in map, you are splitting based on |, but your rows(entities) are separated by space, as I can see. Just verify if that is how the actual data would be. Traditional format would be like, each row(entity) in a single row, and map reduce filters the unique keys after map phase. Once your input is in that format, all you get in reducer are unique keys.

If your input is anything different(like above - 2 records in same line), you need to consider different input format, or handle he logic differently. Understanding how map reduce works and the formats it takes, will help you more. Happy learning

Comment: I did not get what you say. Any hive pipe delimited file will look like 10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
10001|76884|1995-06-24|1996-06-23
10001|75286|1993-06-24|1994-06-24 and the rows are seperated by \n so my key is the first column and value are rest. How does a select distinct column in hive work ?

Comment: Not sure who edited the question. Now it looks fine. So you need to identify the duplicate. I assume the duplicate based on the entire row value and not just first value in that row(separated by I). then you can  keep the output key of map as entire row. (although it dont look good). because generally unique records are identified by a field rather than entire record. Its up to you to decide. based on that you ouput the map key. rest will be taken care by Mapreduce.

Comment: Ramzy I am doing taking the first as key and the rest pair as value so still I can get a key,value pair . And the value are duplicates and not removed. What you are saying is the same thing I am doing. But still no result

Comment: As per your requirement, the unique key is the combination of first and second record, and not just first I suppose. Also please post the output you are getting in reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The idea is only emitting the first value of the Iterable since they are all the same and you want to remove dup values.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class charterSelDistRec {

    public  static class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable ignore, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(value, value);
        }  
    }

    public static class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, NullWritable> {    
      @Override
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
          for (Text value : values){
              context.write(value, NullWritable.get());
              break;
          }
      }
    }       

  /* This is your main. Changed the outputValueClass method only */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();
      Job job = new Job(conf,"charterSelDistRec");
      job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.job.queuename", "root.Dev");
      job.getConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator","|");
      job.setJobName("work_charter_stb.ext_chtr_vod_fyi_mapped");
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

      job.setMapperClass(Map.class);

      job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

      job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
      job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);


      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
      job.setJarByClass(charterSelDistRec.class); 
      job.waitForCompletion(true);
   }
}
```